# Automatically select a date in an UWP CalendarView

Tags: c#, uwp, calendarview

In my UWP app, I want the current day to be automatically selected on a `CalendarView`, but I can't change the value of the `SelectedDates` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SelectedDates` is `List` you can't directly assign a new value to `SelectedDates`. If you use `SelectionMode="Single"` then `Clear` the list and use `Add`.

```
MyCalendarView.SelectedDates.Clear();
MyCalendarView.SelectedDates.Add(DateTimeOffset.Now);
```